# Functor factorization theorem and the structure of a functor

Tags: ct.category-theory, factorization

Corollary 4.8 in [Awodey's book](http://englishonlineclub.com/pdf/Category%20Teory%20%5BEnglishOnlineClub.com%5D.pdf) states that every functor $\mathcal F$:$\mathcal C$$\rightarrow$$\mathcal D$ factors $\mathcal F$ = $\mathcal H$ ◦ $\mathcal G$ where

$\mathcal G$ : $\mathcal C$$\rightarrow$$\mathcal C/ker(F)$ is bijective on objects quotient functor and $\mathcal H$ : $\mathcal C/ker(F)$$\rightarrow$$\mathcal D$ is fully faithful. That is the composite ;

$\mathcal F$:$\mathcal C$$\rightarrow$$\mathcal C/ker(F)$$\rightarrow$$\mathcal D$.

We can also factorize $\mathcal H$ in the way $\mathcal F$ was factorized to obtain $\mathcal H$=$\mathcal H_1$ ◦ $\mathcal G_1$ initializing at  $\mathcal H_0$= $\mathcal H$ and $\mathcal G_0$= $\mathcal G$.

**Question**: upon iterated factorization of $\mathcal H_n$, does this finally converge on $\mathcal D$. And if so, what factorization system generally captures this ? My guess would be reflective-factorizaton systems or monadic decompositon but am looking for a grounded answer.

**EDIT**(4/4/2021): There seems to be two contradictory answers as seen from the comments:

(i) In the factorization $\mathcal H$=$\mathcal H_1$ ◦ $\mathcal G_1$,  $\mathcal H_1$=$\mathcal H$ and $\mathcal G_1$ is the identity on $\mathcal C/ker(F)$

(ii)  An orthogonal factorization system ($\mathcal L$, $\mathcal R$) where the class $\mathcal L$ is of iterated strict-localizations(= iterated quotients) and $\mathcal R$ is the class of conservative functors. It is the factorization of a functor where the iterated quotient converges at the colimit of the transfinite sequence. See relevant links in comments.

How does one unify these two perspectives into one? My current intuition on the problem is that the transfinite sequence is an isomorphism/equivalence(by cancellation laws) and every functor is an iterated strict-localization. Is this true or does it collapse to the first argument?

Comment: In the factorization $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_1\circ\mathcal{G}_1$, isn't $\mathcal{H}_1=\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{G}_1$ the identity functor on $\mathcal{C}/\ker(F)$?

Comment: Am not sure if that's the case:- if you have proof I will gladly accept as an answer. But if am not mistaken, the quotient functor is equivalent to localization and that would vouch for the contrary

Comment: Jeremy is right.  If you factor a fully faithful functor in this way, then the bijective-on-objects first factor will also be fully faithful (since fully faithful functors cancel on one side), and hence an isomorphism.

Comment: This is actually an orthogonal factorization system: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28bo%2C+ff%29+factorization+system, which entails that factorizations are unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: @MikeShulman, I now understand, thank you. I notice from nlab that  orthogonal factorization systems, take examples in duals, e.g epi/mono and that galois connection is both an OFS and an idempotent adjunction. So maybe its worthwhile to ask: under which conditions an OFS is an indempotent adjunction?

Comment: That question doesn't really typecheck as stated, but if you can make it more precise you could ask it as a separate question.

Comment: I find that there is a counter-example(?) [here](https://ncatlab.org/joyalscatlab/show/Factorisation+systems) and also at [example 1.12](https://math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/factorization.pdf). It is an OFS ($\mathcal L$, $\mathcal R$) where the class $\mathcal L$ is of iterated strict localizations and $\mathcal R$ is the class of conservative functors. Infact, it is the factorization of a functor. If this is a valid counter-example, then both perspectives are right and there has to be some resolution that takes both of them into account.

Comment: I am not sure what you think this is a counterexample to.  These are two different factorization systems on Cat.  In one of them the factorization can be constructed by hand in one step.  In the other, there is a naive one-step factorization that is *not* the OFS factorization but can be used to construct it by a transfinite iteration.

Comment: In the Corollary 4.8 that you cite, I see only that the functor you call $\mathcal H$ is faithful, not necessarily fully faithful.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble as am not an expert, so I will rephrase what I think you mean but in my language, that the proposition "strict localization functor is equal to quotient functor" is not true, hence two different factorizations as you have said.

Comment: However, if this [nlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quotient+category#:~:text=Quotient%20category%20is%20an%20alternative,universal%20property%2C%20that%20is%2C%20for) is anything to go by, the proposition is true and by the cancellation laws the iterated quotient from $\mathcal H_0$ to the colimit of the transfinite sequence is an isomorphism. So both views eventually converge in the argument that hinges on the above proposition as well, just like you said that the one-step factorization amounts to the OFS factorization .

Comment: My point hinges on the truth of the above propostion, and if it is true then we maybe missing an important theorem here just because it is well-concealed

Comment: Above I meant, "...iterated quotient from $\mathcal H_1$...", from  $\mathcal C/ker(F)$   not $\mathcal H_0$

Comment: Quotients and localizations are NOT the same. What that nlab page is saying in the first sentence is that some people refer to (or used to refer to) localizations as quotients.

Comment: OKay, I concede that am wrong, maybe I write up a rigorous answer later

Comment: Reid and Kori, it is not that some call general localizations quotients, but only some specific classes of quotient like constructions of localized categories (most notably Serre quotient category in Abelian context and its triangulated analogue) have standard terminology quotients. This likely stems from ring theory where quotient skewfields of domains (Ore, Goldie etc.) are considered (they are not quotients by ideals but typically epis in the category of rings, thus localizations).  I know nobody who says "iterated quotient" for the colimit above (iterated strict localization by Joyal).